# Minecraft server will just not forward!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Im sure you have seen too many of these, however i do have a good amount of info on what im using, and variations of what i have tried

Router Linksys E1200 (N300)
Computer OS: Windows 8.1 AND Windows 10 (same difference)
Architecture: x64 (with Java 8/7/6 x64)

Yes, i have allowed exceptions to my windows firewall for java/bin/java.exe AND javaw.exe

Yes, i have forwarded the port through my router at 25565 with TCP and UDP with my computers LOCAL address included correctly.

I have tried for the [server-ip] to be empty, my local ip, and for some reason i even tried my public ip.

I have even tried disabling my entire firewall...

Am i missing something here? I mean, i have never run a basement server, but i do some networking in programming, so i should be binding to my local address right? I have my internal and external ports set to 25565, so localhost is still localhost without a port.

Nevertheless, still i cannot connect. I am hosting my server from an isp and using my other computer via mobile hotspot (which does fine with my hosted server) to connect. No results.

Comment: Are you sure your ISP itself is not blocking incoming connections on port 25565?

Comment: Also, would this question best be moved somewhere like server fault or network engineer?

Comment: Have you set any trigger ports on your modem? *If not, don't. If you have, remove their definitions in the modem config!!* (Some people go nuts and fill their config with 25565 in every field, which breaks stuff)

Comment: No i diddnt set any 25565 port but the single port forward. I'm pretty sure my isp isnt...

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned windows firewall -- when you 'allowed java' you're allowing it *normally* to connect outwards

This won't, by default, allow it to connect IN to your system.

You need to open the minecraft ports, on your windows firewall, from anywhere.

Comment: I mean, do you mean inbound connections? Because i added that through the advanced section where you define both tcp and udp inbound connections. I added 25565 for both. From the windows firewall in the control panel